# Cannot read property 'customer_name' of undefined from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Below is my JSON response

```
{  
   "status":"success",
   "results":[  
      {  
         "customer_id":"179",
         "customer_name":"satishakarma",
         "customer_email":"satish@gmail.com",
         "customer_username":"satish",
         "customer_mobileno":"9876543210",
         "game_amount":"1200"
      }
   ]
}
```

This is js code

```
      success:function(e){
        var d = JSON.parse(e);
        if (d.status === 'success') {
          //window.location="game.html";\
          var user =  (JSON.stringify(d));
          console.log(user);
          console.log(user.results.customer_name);
          //localStorage.setItem(d.customer_name,d.game_amount);
        }else
        {
          alert('Username and Password Invslid');
        }
      }
```

I want to take customer name from response for that

I wrote `console.log(user.results.customer_name);` to print in console. but getting `Cannot read property 'customer_name' of undefined` error. How to take customer name from this api?

Comment: Results is an array, so you need `user.results[0].customer_name`

Comment: try `console.log(user.results[0].customer_name);` since results is array

Comment: When you `stringify`, you turn an object into a string. Strings, of course, do not have a `results` property.

Comment: @CertainPerformance. So in this case what i have to do?. I'm new to this

Comment: @CertainPerformance thanks. After removing stringify it works.

Answer (score 2):

Since, you have only one `results` array in your `user` object you need to access that using the `user.results[0]`.

```js
var user = {  
   "status":"success",
   "results":[  
      {  
         "customer_id":"179",
         "customer_name":"satishakarma",
         "customer_email":"satish@gmail.com",
         "customer_username":"satish",
         "customer_mobileno":"9876543210",
         "game_amount":"1200"
      }
   ]
}

console.log(user.results[0].customer_name);
```

But, if you have more than one object in the `results` array then you can use loop over that array:

```js
var user = {  
   "status":"success",
   "results":[  
      {  
         "customer_id":"179",
         "customer_name":"satishakarma",
         "customer_email":"satish@gmail.com",
         "customer_username":"satish",
         "customer_mobileno":"9876543210",
         "game_amount":"1200"
      },
       {  
         "customer_id":"180",
         "customer_name":"satishakarma2",
         "customer_email":"satish2@gmail.com",
         "customer_username":"satish2",
         "customer_mobileno":"9876543210",
         "game_amount":"1200"
      }
   ]
}

user.results.forEach(obj=>console.log(obj.customer_name));
```

Also make sure that the `user` variable has object instead of a stringified JSON. If that is a string variable then you need to parse it to JSON otherwise you will get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`

```js
var user = `{  
   "status":"success",
   "results":[  
      {  
         "customer_id":"179",
         "customer_name":"satishakarma",
         "customer_email":"satish@gmail.com",
         "customer_username":"satish",
         "customer_mobileno":"9876543210",
         "game_amount":"1200"
      }
   ]
}`;
user = JSON.parse(user);

console.log(user.results[0].customer_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's in an array...

```
console.log(user.results[0].customer_name)
```

Comment: Is your object truly named `user`? You don't provide enough code to determine that.

Comment: @SagarKodte checked the third snippet in my answer. That should be your solution

Answer (score 1):

`console.log(user.results[0].customer_name)`

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to,

```
success:function(e){
        var d = JSON.parse(e);
        if (d.status === 'success') {
          //window.location="game.html";\
          var user =  d;
          console.log(user);
          console.log(user.results[0].customer_name);
          //localStorage.setItem(d.customer_name,d.game_amount);
        }else
        {
          alert('Username and Password Invslid');
        }
      }
```

Now you will be able to see the correct result.
You had stringified the object which made it impossible to call using the dot operator.